# ORDER BY entre duas colunas datetime

Tags: mysql, select, datetime, order-by

Possuo duas colunas datetime: data1 e data2.

Preciso ordenar pela menor data entre as duas colunas.

Se data2 não for zero, exibe linha data2;

Se data2 for zero, exibe linha data1;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço? Por favor, obrigado.

Comment: Resolvi assim:


SELECT `data1`, `data2`, REPLACE(`data2`,'0000-00-00 00:00:00', date(`data1`)) ordena FROM `tabela` ORDER BY ordena ASC